# How to create a shared document library in SharePoint that can be used in subsites?

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

We want to create a common document library on a certain site level and then create views on that document library in the different sub sites?
Is that possible in SharePoint?
Can it be done declaratively?

Rine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the **DataFormWebPart** (requires SharePoint Designer to insert and customize the **DFWP**, the result can be exported to a feature)

The following blog entry lists a suitable SPDataSource sample:
[SPDataSource and Rollups with the Data View](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.  You will either need a third party "roll-up" ("roll-down") web part or you will need to write your own.  OTB, views for lists/libraries are only visible at the current site level.

That being said, roll-ups (in one form or another) are probably one of the most common 3rd party seller for sharepoint (just a guess).  In fact, I would bet there are several free projects out there that you could use (Check codeplex).  You should have no problem finding one that meets your needs.

My suggestion would be to write your own, as this would give you some real good experience using the SharePoint object model and there really are no complicated concepts.  Once you get past being able to do site navigation and accessing list data through the OM, you pretty much have all the tools you need.

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

I have found a cheep and great webpart which does a documents rollup from all subsites with search, paging and sorting functions.
http://speasysolution.miiduu.com/es-sharepoint-2010-documents-rollup

i used it, its simple and powerful